# Can this be considered an independent clause without a subject?

Tags: independent-clauses

In the sentence:

> *If you're a boy, aim well.*

Is the statement "*aim well*" considered an independent clause even without a subject? If not, then what is it?

Answer (score 1):

The if-clause is the subclause, the imperative "aim well" is the main clause. The subject you is implied in the imperative. You should ask such basic question on ELL for learners.